# take out number from string

Tags: javascript

I get a string from my javascript. These strings look like this: 2x2 3x3 and so on.

Now I would like to get the numbers from these strings. What should I do to get 2 from 2x2 and save that number in a variable?

Comment: Yes it will always be the same number before and after x

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex:

```
var foo = '2x32';
var matches = foo.match(/^(\d+)x(\d+)$/);
if (matches.length > 2) {
    var a = matches[1]; // = 2
    var b = matches[2]; // = 32
}
```

Comment: +1 for fail safe approach. Should contain `^` and `$` anchors, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str     = "2x2";   
var numbers = str.split("x"); // ["2","2"]
var first   = numbers[0];     // "2"
```

Or, for short

```
"2x2".split("x")[0];          // "2"
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. `string.split` seems better than regex for such a simple scenario.